# \includeonlyproblems{}

Tags: package-writing

I have a collection of problems which I use to make tests, homeworks, etc.
All problems are in one LaTeX file each problem is in it's own
`\begin{problem}\end{problem}` environment. Every time I need to make a
new exam/homework I copy-paste problems to a new LaTeX file. It would be
much easier if I had `\includeonlyproblems{}` mechanism, similar to what can be found in the LaTeX songs package http://songs.sourceforge.net/

Do you know if something like that already exists?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You could use a little bit of `expl3` and have an if–then construct that conditionally starts a `comment` from the `verbatim` package, IIRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `exsheets` package allows this by including problems selectively via ID, or topic, or ... from an external file:

```
% the external file:
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{myproblems.tex}
\begin{problem}[topic=A,ID=A1]
  problem 1 (A:1)
\end{problem}
\begin{problem}[topic=B,ID=B1]
  problem 2 (B:1)
\end{problem}
\begin{problem}[topic=A,ID=A2]
  problem 3 (A:2)
\end{problem}
\begin{problem}[topic=B,ID=B2]
  problem 4 (B:2)
\end{problem}
\begin{problem}[topic=A,ID=A3]
  problem 5 (A:3)
\end{problem}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{exsheets}
% \DebugExSheets{true}
\NewQuSolPair{problem}{answer}

\begin{document}

\section{By ID}
\includequestions[IDs={A1,A2,B2}]{myproblems.tex}

\section{By Topic}
\SetupExSheets{use-topics={B}}
\includequestions{myproblems.tex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @cgnieder.  Thank you a lot. Unfortunately there is a bug in the package. 
`code`
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{aaa.tex}
\begin{problem}[subtitle=problem 1,topic=A,ID=A1]
 This one has subtitle ``problem 1.'' 
\end{problem}
\begin{problem}[subtitle=problem 2,topic=A,ID=A2]
 This one has subtitle ``problem 2.'' 
\end{problem}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[load-headings=true]{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{headings=block-subtitle}
\NewQuSolPair{problem}{answer}
\begin{document}
\includequestions[IDs={A1,A2}]{aaa.tex}
\end{document}

Comment: Sorry about the cryptic comment, but I do not know how to include code in the comments.